# mapreduce difference in count

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to write a program that outputs the differences between counts in 2 columns. So my data looks like this:

```
2,1
2,3
1,2
3,1
4,2
```

I want to count the occurrences of key in col1 and the occurrences of keys in col2 and take the difference. The output should look like this:

```
1,-1
2,0
3,0
4,1
```

can this be done in one mapreduce procedure(mapper,reducer)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mapper for each line you will create two keys, one for col1 and another for col2 where values are count from each columns, like so:

2,1 -> 2:{1, 0} and 1:{0, 1}

2,3 -> 2:{1, 0} and 3:{0, 1}

1,2 -> 1:{1, 0} and 2:{0, 1}

3,1 -> 3:{1, 0} and 1:{0, 1}

4,2 -> 4:{1, 0} and 2:{0, 1}

Then in reducer you will get these results where each line is the key and values combination for each `reduce` call:

1 -> {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1} (adding them will produce -1)

2 -> {1, 0}, 2:{1, 0}, 2:{0, 1}, 2:{0, 1} (adding them will produce 0)

3 -> {0, 1}, {1, 0} (adding them will produce 0)

4 -> {1, 0} (adding them will produce 1)

**Update:**

Here is Hadoop example (it is not tested and might require some tweaking to get it working):

```
public class TheMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, ArrayPrimitiveWritable>{        

    protected void map(LongWritable offset, Text value, Context context) 
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer( value.toString(), "," );

        Text col1 = new Text( tok.nextToken() );
        context.write( col1, toArray(1, 0) );

        Text col2 = new Text( tok.nextToken() );        
        context.write( col2, toArray(0, 1) );
    }

    private ArrayPrimitiveWritable toArray(int v1, int v2){     
        return new ArrayPrimitiveWritable( new int[]{i1, i2} );
    }   
}

public class TheReducer extends Reducer<Text, ArrayPrimitiveWritable, Text, Text> {

  public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<ArrayPrimitiveWritable> values, Context context) 
  throws IOException, InterruptedException {

      Iterator<ArrayPrimitiveWritable> i = values.iterator();
      int count = 0;
      while ( i.hasNext() ){
          int[] counts = (int[])i.next().get();
          count += counts[0];
          count -= counts[1];
      }

      context.write( key, new Text("" + count) );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i get the logic. How would you implement this in Java? do you need 2 object keys in public void map{}?

Comment: This is a great solution and worked for me, however, I am curious why you used Text instead of IntWritable, since we are dealing with numerical node degrees.